# Simple PL/SQL Code will not run. I cannot find the error

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I've been tweaking and trying to debug this PL/SQL code for like 4 hours now. I have also tried to search on here but it is so specific that I really need help. Here is my code, When I try to run it, the two prompt questions pop up. After I answer the second one, oracle just stops running.

```
---- File PLh20.sql 
-- Author: <<< NAME >>> 
------------------------------------------------------------------- 
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON 
    SET VERIFY OFF
------------------------------------ 
ACCEPT rateDecrement NUMBER PROMPT 'Enter the rate decrement: ' 
ACCEPT allowedMinRate NUMBER PROMPT 'Enter the allowed min. rate: ' 
DECLARE 
 sr boats%ROWTYPE; 
 CURSOR sCursor IS 
 SELECT B.bid, B.bname, B.color, B.rate, B.length, B.logKeeper 
 FROM Boats B
     WHERE B.bid NOT IN (SELECT bid FROM Reservations);

BEGIN 
 OPEN sCursor; 
 LOOP 
 -- Fetch the qualifying rows one by one 
 FETCH sCursor INTO sr; 
 EXIT WHEN sCursor%NOTFOUND;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('+++++ old rate: '||sr.rate||' ' 
 ||sr.rate||); 
  sr.rate := sr.rate - &rateDecrement; 

-- A nested block 
 DECLARE 
 belowAllowedMin EXCEPTION; 
 BEGIN 
 IF sr.rate < &allowedMinRate 
 THEN RAISE belowAllowedMin; 
 ELSE UPDATE Boats 
 SET rate = sr.rate 
 WHERE Boats.bid = sr.bid; 
 -- Print the boat new record
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('+++++ new row: '||sr.bid||' ' 
 ||sr.rate||); 
 END IF; 
 EXCEPTION 
 WHEN belowAllowedMin THEN 
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('+++++ Update rejected: '|| 
 'The new rate would have been: '|| sr.rate); 
 WHEN OTHERS THEN 
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('+++++ update rejected: ' || 
 SQLCODE||'...'||SQLERRM); 
 END; 
 -- end of the nested block 
END LOOP; 
 COMMIT; 
 CLOSE sCursor; 
END; 

SELECT S.sid, S.rating 
FROM sailors S, reservations R, boats B 
WHERE S.sid = R.sid AND 
 R.bid = B.bid;

UNDEFINE rateDecrement
UNDEFINE allowedMinRate
```

Comment: What's the error and paste relevant SQL only ?

Comment: how fast does just the basic query take to run? `select ... from boats where ...` ? Good luck.

Comment: Indent your code for G0d sakes...

Comment: Get the number of records in your cursor...

Comment: All of that code is relevant. I run it, enter in the two prompts and then it just stops. Im using sqlplus in linux.

Comment: It takes about .25 seconds to run. I tried running it in Oracle application express too. This is the error I get although I often get weird errors that are not really it with apex.

Comment: ORA-06550: line 15, column 13: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following: ( - + case mod new null <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> continue avg count current max min prior sql stddev sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval date <a string literal with character set specification> <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>

Answer (score 1):

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('+++++ new row: '||sr.bid||' '||sr.rate||);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('+++++ old rate: '||sr.rate||' '||sr.rate||);
```

Looks like these 2 are the problem. There should not be '||' at the end.

Comment: I took out the last two ||. But it still does the same thing.